# Python regex group clarification

Tags: python, regex

I have 0 experience with python, very little with regex and I'm trying to figure out what this small snippet of
python regex would give back from a http response header Set-Cookie entry:

```
REGEX_COOKIE = '([A-Z]+=[^;]+;)'
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
re.search(REGEX_COOKIE, resp.info()['Set-Cookie']).group(1)
```

Can one give a simple example of a Set-Cookie value and explain what this would match on + return?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Set-Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) is a list of name value pairs, separated with semi-colons:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: RMID=732423sdfs73242; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2010 23:59:59 GMT

(content of page)
```

The regular expression matches the name, the equals sign, and the value up to the first semi-colon - in this case: `RMID=732423sdfs73242;`. In other words, it reads the first name-value pair. Note that it won't work if there is only a single name-value pair which is not followed by a semi-colon.

Comment: Thanks, clear explanation.
If I'm with you, for a Set-Cookie string like this Set-Cookie: RMID=732423sdfs73242; path=/; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2010 23:59:59 GMT
, group(2) would match on RMID=732423sdfs73242; path=/;  ?

Comment: @nkr1pt: Actually, no it will only find the first. To find all name value pairs you could use re.findall, or even simpler: don't bother with regular expressions, just use str.split(';').